# Minimum raw material, maximum sets

Tags: excel, matrix, minimum, inventory, venn

Appreciate if anyone can help.

I have the below:

- list of raw material (150 items).
- list of finished products (130 products).
- BOM (bill of material), in which every product contains about 5 of the raw material, and ofcourse some product may share the same raw material with other products.

My question is .. away from any financial profits, how can i select or define the minimum number of raw material that can produce maximum amount of products.

In other words .. lets say i want to select 20 or 30 raw material to maintain .. which one should i keep to have the maximum production.

Is there a way to do it in excel?

Comment: Do some research on here, this has been asked and answered several times.

Comment: @ahmed - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well.. i made a pivot on excel .. found out how many times the raw material appeared in the finished products .. i did eliminate the ones which appeared only once .. and kept eliminating till i reached 30 raw material.
I know it is totally not accurate, but still searching for a way.